# How to create muttiple filter menus for html table

Tags: jquery, html, css

hi can you guy's please help i have a fiddle with menus setup already just need to set them up to hide table rows on click but i must be able to use more than one to filter even more my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/poz9dwhg/)

```
<div class="filters">

                <div id="filterRegion" class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="currentRegionLabel">All Regions</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="All Regions">All Regions</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="La Noscea">Region A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="Black Shroud">Region B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-value="Thanalan">Region C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="filterQuestType" class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="alltype">all</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="mainq">main</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="sideq">side</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="leveq">leve</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="guildq">guild</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filtertype" data-qtype="loreq">lore</label>
                </div>

                <div id="filterLvl" class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="60">all</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="20">1-10</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="20">11-20</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="21" data-end="80">21-30</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="20">31-40</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="20">41-50</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterSet" data-start="1" data-end="20">51-60</label>
                </div>

                <div id="filterCompletion" class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" name="filterCompletion" data-filter="allduty">all</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterCompletion" data-filter="todo">todo</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="filterCompletion" data-filter="done">done</label>
                </div>
</div>
```